# Extracting Key, Value pair from YAML file using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, yaml

I've the YAML file, where i need to get the (Key, Value) Pair out of it. Below is the loadYAML method written to load the YAML file.

```
def loadYAML(path: String): String = {
      val yaml = scala.io.Source.fromFile(yamlPath).getLines().mkString(" \n ")
      val yamlReader = new ObjectMapper((new YAMLFactory))
      val obj = yamlReader.readValue(yaml, classOf[Any])
      val jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper
      jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(obj)
    }

val yaml = loadYAML(yamlPath)
```

Passing the `key(CUSTOMER_VEHICLE)` and yaml string to `getConfig` method to get the required variables output.

```
def getConfig(key: String)(yaml: String): (List[String], List[String], HashMap[String, String], HashMap[String, String]) = {
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val json = parse(yaml)
  val null_CheckFields = (json  \\ key \ "null_check_fields").extract[List[String]]
  val primary_key = (json \\ key \ "primary_key").extract[List[String]]
  val reference_check = (json \\ key \ "reference_check").extract[HashMap[String, String]]
  val date_fields = (json \\ key \\ "date_fields").extract[HashMap[String, String]]
  (null_CheckFields, primary_key, date_fields)
}



val (null_CheckFields, primary_key, reference_check, date_fields) = getConfig(sourceName)(yaml)
```

As result of output, i'm getting the correct output for null_CheckFields, primary_key variables but getting the below error for the other two variables(reference_check,date_fields).

YAML FILE:

```
 source_name: 
  CUSTOMER_VEHICLE:
    date_fields: 
      Vehicle_delivery_date:
        - "yyyy/MM/dd"
      shaken_due_dates: 
        - "yyyy/MM/dd"
      tenken_due_dates: 
        - "yyyy/MM/dd"
    null_check_fields:
      - truck_vin_no    
      - truck_plate_no
    primary_key: 
      - truck_vin_no
      - truck_plate_no
      
  DEALER_MASTER:
    date_fields: 
      opening_time: 
        - "HH:mm"
      closing_time: 
        - "HH:mm"
    null_check_fields: 
      - dealer_code
    primary_key: 
      - dealer_code
```

Error:

```
val date_fields = (json \\ "CUSTOMER_VEHICLE" \\ "date_fields").extract[HashMap[String, String]]



 args=
arg types=
executable=Executable(Constructor(public java.util.HashMap(int)))
cause=wrong number of arguments
types comparison result=MISSING(int)
    at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:95)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.instantiate(Extraction.scala:573)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.result(Extraction.scala:597)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$$anonfun$extract$6.apply(Extraction.scala:400)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$$anonfun$extract$6.apply(Extraction.scala:392)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.customOrElse(Extraction.scala:606)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:392)
    at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:39)
    at org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:1)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:59)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:61)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:63)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:65)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:67)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:69)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:71)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:73)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1263271695000185:75)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read.<init>(command-1263271695000185:77)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$.<init>(command-1263271695000185:81)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$read$.<clinit>(command-1263271695000185)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at line0b7611b451ce487d885fd2af6609688d41.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:699)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:652)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:385)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I don't know much Scala, but the `source_name` key seems to be missing when accessing the JSON values.

Comment: Can you please accept or upvote if below solution helps .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `val date_fields = (json \\ key \\ "date_fields").extract[HashMap[String, String]]` to   `val date_fields = (json \\ key \\ "date_fields").extract[HashMap[String, List[String]]]`, It will work.

Check below code.

```
def getConfig(key: String)(yaml: String): (List[String], List[String], HashMap[String, List[String]], HashMap[String, List[String]]) = {
  import org.json4s._
  import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  val json = parse(yaml)
  val null_CheckFields = (json  \\ key \ "null_check_fields").extract[List[String]]
  val primary_key = (json \\ key \ "primary_key").extract[List[String]]
  val reference_check = (json \\ key \ "reference_check").extract[HashMap[String, List[String]]]
  val date_fields = (json \\ key \\ "date_fields").extract[HashMap[String, List[String]]]
  (null_CheckFields, primary_key, date_fields)
}
```

You can also check - [circe-yaml](https://github.com/circe/circe-yaml) library to convert `yaml` to `json` to `case classes`.